# Push var data into other page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I work an a mobile app with ionic, I have to push a variable into an other Page

I've tried to use NavController.push but I have an error : 
Property 'push' does not exist on type 'NavController'

```
<ion-card (click)="passVar(item.HISTO_N)" *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title #HISTO_N>Intervention n° {{item.HISTO_N}}</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content style="margin-top: 10px;">
         <p style="text-decoration: underline;margin-top: 10px;">Adresse :</p><p [innerHTML]="item.L4_Livraison"><br></p>
         <p style="text-decoration: underline;margin-top: 10px;">Date : </p><p [innerHTML]="item.HISTO_Date1"></p>
         <p style="text-decoration: underline;margin-top: 10px;">Consigne : </p><p [innerHTML]="item.HISTO_Comm1"><br></p>
         <ion-button float-right fill="clear" *ngIf="item.HISTO_Objet2 == null" color="warning">
          <ion-icon name="information-circle"></ion-icon>&nbsp;Etat non renseigné
       .
       .
       .
       .
    </ion-card>
```

```
passVar(HISTO_N) {
    HISTO_N = HISTO_N || 'ERROR NO VAR';

    this.navCtrl.push(Tab1Page, {
      data: HISTO_N
    });
    console.log(HISTO_N);

  }
```

Comment: Whitch ionic version are you using. (`ionic -v` e.g. `5.2.5`)

Comment: ionic -v return 5.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 4+ dont support `pust pop` navigation anymore, its now using [Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/router).

If you want to use routing in ionic 4+ and learn how to pass params and all the good stuff try out their [blog post](https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-change-with-ionic-4-and-angular-router/) about the changes due to routing.